# Make the TouchBar show app controls for one specific app at all times

Tags: macos, mac, touch-bar

Say I want to have control over my music regardless of which app I have active on the front. I want the music controls exclusively.

This is just an example. I would like it to be possible for any app. Not just Music.

Answer (score 1):

In order to always show the “default” set of keys, like on older MacBooks, go to `Settings > Keyboard`.

Then find the `Touch Bar shows` control and set it to, `Expanded Control Strip`.

This way, the music controls are always in front.

Comment: this does not answer the question. Audio controls != app controls for specific app

Comment: It actually is because this blocks all other apps from using the touchbar

Comment: no, it does not "show app controls for one specific app at all times".  You provided workaround just for the Music, but it does not actually show app controls for the specific app but rather global audio controls.